# Eclipse Plugin : I want to control the display of the console. What should I do?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Some exception information is printed on the console
example

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Content displayed on the console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at test.org.eclipse.ui.internal.A5_Test.tearDownAfterClass(A5_Test.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
```

i want ...

```
if( string.startsWith("    at") ){
    //dont display
}
```

i tried to use **org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleLineTrackers** extension point, but failed

```
@Override
public void lineAppended(IRegion line) {
    try {
        String string = console.getDocument().get( line.getOffset() , line.getLength() ) ;
        if( string.startsWith("    at") ) {
            console.getDocument().replace( line.getOffset() , line.getLength() + 2 , "" ) ;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // There are no exceptions here
    }
}
```

result : Only four lines were successfully replaced

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at test.org.eclipse.ui.internal.A5_Test.tearDownAfterClass(A5_Test.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
```

How should I solve this problem? thank you .

Comment: `removePosition` is nothing to do with modifying the text. `replace` looks possible - exacty what error does that give? Show us the stack trace if there is one.

Comment: I updated the problem description , thank you

Comment: My guess would be that the code calling the line tracker does not expect it to change the document and gets confused about match positions if it does. Looking at other line trackers all they do is call console.addLink.

Comment: I agree.
Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: The only use I can see of `replace` is in `IOConsolePartitioner` which use a `UIJob` to run the replace asynchronously.